# Appcelerator Android SDK - Could not find sdk at the given path

Tags: android, sdk, titanium

I am trying to give path in Titanium Studio for the android sdk. But it gives the following error: `can't find android sdk at the given path`. I cannot install sdk from the dashboard. Please help.

```
Host OS: Windows 7

OS Arch: x86

JRE Version: 1.6.0_24


JRE Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.

JRE Home: C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\jre

Install Directory: file:/C:/Users/Bonny/AppData/Local/Titanium Studio/

Eclipse Version: 3.6.2.R36x_v20110210

VM Arguments: -Xms40m

-Xmx1024m

-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow

-Djava.awt.headless=true

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m


-Djava.class.path=C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Local\Titanium 

Studio\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

Workspace Directory: file:/C:/Users/Bonny/My Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/

Language: en_IN

Titanium Desktop SDK Version: 1.1.0

Titanium Desktop SDK Location: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\sdk\win32\1.1.0

Titanium Mobile SDK Version: 1.7.5

Mobile SDK Timestamp: 11/02/11 17:00

Mobile SDK Build Number: ab20af7

Titanium Mobile SDK Location: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.7.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following links from the developer forum

1. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121567/could-not-locate-the-android-sdk-at-a-given-path-in-preferences--android-sdk-directory
2. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122998/could-not-locate-the-android-sdk-at-the-given-path
3. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127541/titanium-cannot-find-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows Environment variables, make sure `ANDROID_HOME` is set to the correct path.

If you don't know how to do that:

- Control Panel
- System
- Advanced System Settings (on the left)
- Environment Variables
- Find `ANDROID_HOME` in the "User variables for YOUR_USERNAME", click `ANDROID_HOME` and click "Edit...". Then type in the path to your Android SDK.
- Restart Titanium.